# can't get my image to resize in CSS

Tags: css

This is my current code and the problem now is that image3, which is the 2nd box is not showing the correct height... The following is the updated code for my style.css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial', 'serif';
}

.nav {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   color: #000000;
   list-style: none;
   text-align: right;
   padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.nav > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #c1c1c1;
}

.logo {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.logo > a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color:black;
}

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}

.banner > .banner-image {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 700;
}

.service1 {
    width: 298px;
    border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    float: left;
}

.service1 > p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #636363;
    max-width: 200px;
    text-align: justify;

}

.services {
    width: 1500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 -6px;
}

.image {
    max-width: 135px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.heading {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #000000;
    margin:100px 0 50px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.service1 > image1 {
    max-width: 120;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.service1 > image3 {
    max-width: 120;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}


.image:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    max-width: 200px;
     margin-top:15px;
}

.image1:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-top:15px;
 }

.message {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.message ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

This is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Pianocourse101</title>
</head>
<body>



   <ul class="nav">

      <div class="logo">
         <a href="index.html">Pianocourse101</a>
      </div>



  <li><a href="http://localhost/pianocourse101/register.php">Register</li> 
      </a>
  <li><a href="http://localhost/pianocourse101/login.php">Login</li></a>

  <li><a href="">About Me</li></a> 
  <li><a href="">Contact Us</li></a>
```

```
   <div class="banner">
      <img class="banner-image" src="images/mervin.gif">
   </div>

   <br></br>
   <br></br>
   <div class="message">
      <p> At Pianocourse101, you will learn the following</p>
         <ul>
            <li>Basic hand positions</li>
            <li>Posture</li>
            <li>Rhythm</li>
            <li>Finger numbers</li>
            <li>Letter names</li>
         </ul>
   </div>


   <div class="heading">Services</div>
      <div align="center" class="services">
         <div class="service1">  
            <h1>Download Section: Primer Level</h1>
            <a href=""><img class="image1" src="images/treble.png"></a>
            <p>Access full contents for just <strong>$50!</strong> Learn the 
 basic hand positions, finger numbers and letter names!</p>
         </div>


    <div class="service1">  
        <h1>Download Section: Level 1</h1>
        <a href=""><img class="image3" src="images/bass.jpg"></a>
        <p>Access full contents for just <strong>$100!</strong> Learn some 
    advanced pieces, slurs and staccatos!</p>

      </div>


     <div class="service1">  
        <h1>Download Section: Level 2</h1>
        <a href=""><img class="image" src="images/crotchet.png"></a>
        <p>Access full contents for just <strong>$150!</strong> Progress and 
    play some more advanced pieces hands together!</p>
     </div>

      <div class="service1">  
        <h1>Download Section: Level 3</h1>
        <a href=""><img class="image2" src="images/bass.jpg"></a>
        <p>Access full contents for just <strong>200!</strong> Feeling more 
     confident and need a challenge? Level 3 will provide you with more 
        challenging pieces!</p>
         </div>
       </div>

   <section>

   </section>
   <footer>

   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why I have to add more comments but I can't figure out why my second box is not lining up correctly...

/* CSS alignment is read as top, left, bottom, right*/

Comment: Sorry guys.. My apologies.. There was a typo in my img src..... Sorry

Comment: I got another problem though and I want to use my own picture which has 2048 by 1536 but it doesn't look correct when I shring the height. What kind of resolution work best?

Comment: You have a typo in the img tag: `class="bannner-image"` with 3 n's. This causes the css for it to be ignored and the image to display at its natural size.

Comment: Also, you seem to think that the end tag for <a> elements is optional. Best run your HTML through a validator. And as to your last comment: if you mean the order of the sides in CSS, that would be top right bottom left. Clockwise.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it to work!